# x-axis tick marks not appearing in graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, visualization

I'm trying to get months and years to show up in a 'Mon YYYY' format on the x-axis, but so far I'm only able to get the years to show up.

I've tried using variations of

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

without success.

Here is what `df['login_month']` (what I'm trying to display as the x-axis) looks like:

```
index   login_month
0       2016-01-01 00:00:00
1       2016-02-01 00:00:00
2       2016-03-01 00:00:00
3       2016-04-01 00:00:00
4       2016-05-01 00:00:00
5       2016-06-01 00:00:00
6       2016-07-01 00:00:00
7       2016-08-01 00:00:00
8       2016-09-01 00:00:00
9       2016-10-01 00:00:00
10      2016-11-01 00:00:00
11      2016-12-01 00:00:00
12      2017-01-01 00:00:00
13      2017-02-01 00:00:00
14      2017-03-01 00:00:00
15      2017-04-01 00:00:00
16      2017-05-01 00:00:00
17      2017-06-01 00:00:00
18      2017-07-01 00:00:00
19      2017-08-01 00:00:00
20      2017-09-01 00:00:00
21      2017-10-01 00:00:00
22      2017-11-01 00:00:00
23      2017-12-01 00:00:00
24      2018-01-01 00:00:00
25      2018-02-01 00:00:00
26      2018-03-01 00:00:00
```

The code I have right now is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

df['login_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['login_month'])

ax = (df.pivot(index='login_month',
          columns='user_month_created',
          values='cumulative_logins')
   .plot.area(figsize=(20,18))
)

#labels
plt.title('cumulative monthly logins by user creation cohort month')
plt.xlabel('login month')
plt.ylabel('cumulative monthly logins (in tens of millions)')

# # ticks
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
# ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
# ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))

# # round to nearest years.
# datemin = np.datetime64(df['login_month'][0], 'M')
# datemax = np.datetime64(df['login_month'][1294], 'M') + np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
# area_plot.set_xlim(xmin=datemin, xmax=datemax)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 12000000, 250000))
plt.grid(True)
```

and it currently plots:
[image]

and it's missing the months and years in the tick marks

**@baccandr**
When I tried to reproduce your result, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError module 'matplotlib.dates' has no attribute 'ConciseDateFormatter' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-49dd880fcf13> in <module>
     14 
     15 locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=15, maxticks=30)
---> 16 formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
     17 axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
     18 axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.dates' has no attribute 'ConciseDateFormatter'
```

[image]

and the following graph 
[image]

Comment: It looks like your example code is almost [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you don't show how to load the data into `df`. It will be easier for people to help if you show that.

Comment: @DonKirkby noted! will add in a representative data set next time too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
if you are still running on **matplotlib 2.2.x** you could use [matplotlib ticker](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.4/api/ticker_api.html) api:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
#generate some random data
idx= pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2020-02-01',freq='m')
df=pd.DataFrame({'rand1':np.random.random(len(idx)),
                 'rand2': np.random.random(len(idx)),
                 'rand3': np.random.random(len(idx))},index=idx)
#stack plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,18),constrained_layout=True)
axs.stackplot(df.index,df.rand1,df.rand2,df.rand3)

#Adjust ticks
axs.set_xticks(pd.to_datetime(idx.year.unique().astype(str)), minor=False)
axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(idx.year.unique().astype(str)))

#create bimonthly minor ticks
months=pd.date_range(start=idx[0], end=idx[-1],freq='2M')
axs.set_xticks(pd.to_datetime(months), minor=True)
axs.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(months.month.astype(str)))

#adjust major ticks aesthetics
axs.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',length=5,width=1.5, pad=4, labelsize=14)
```

If you want to display less/more months you can simply adjust the frequency in `pd.date_range(start=idx[0], end=idx[-1],freq='2M')`.

This is the result:
[image]

**For matplotlib 3.1.x:**

I would probably use the matplotlib [auto date locator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator) together with the [concise date formatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter):

```
#generate some random data
idx= pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2020-01-01',freq='m')
df=pd.DataFrame({'rand1':np.random.random(len(idx)),
                 'rand2': np.random.random(len(idx)),
                 'rand3': np.random.random(len(idx))},index=idx)
#stack plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,18),constrained_layout=True)
axs.stackplot(df.index,df.rand1,df.rand2,df.rand3)

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=15, maxticks=20)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

By changing the argument of the autodatelocator you can adjust the frequency of your ticks. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html) you can also find some examples on how to change the output of the concise date formatter.

**p.s.**
I used matplotlib stackplot function but you should be able to obtain a similar result also using pandas plot.area function.

**p.p.s**
with your example I was not able to reproduce your issue because the date span is too short and the automatic formatter from pandas just worked fine.

this is the result I got:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply! When I added your suggestions to my code, I got the same error as when I ran your example code. Is it an issue with my editor?

Comment: the cConciseDateFormatter class was introduced with matplotlib 3.1, which version are you using?

Comment: it looks like i'm currently stuck on matplotlib 2.2.3 for now...no wonder it didn't work. thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @davviid I modify my answer including an alternative solution that should works also for older matplotlib versions. Let me know if this works for you as well!